# Unable to convert string to date (Portuguese locale)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert a string in a date column, as 13-mai-2019,

but when I use the following code:`datetime.datetime.strptime('23-mai-2019', '%d-%B-%Y').strftime('%d-%B-%Y')`
I got the following error:
`ValueError: time data '23-mai-2019' does not match format '%d-%B-%Y'`
Please could you give a hint how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Use date parsing library called [`dateparser`](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/):

```
import dateparser

print (dateparser.parse('13-mai-2019'))
2019-05-13 00:00:00

print (dateparser.parse('13-mai-2019').strftime('%d-%B-%Y'))
13-May-2019
```

For working with date column use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['13-mai-2019','13-mai-2019']})
print(df)
          date
0  13-mai-2019
1  13-mai-2019

import dateparser

df['date_new'] = df['date'].apply(dateparser.parse)
df['date_new_en'] = df['date'].apply(dateparser.parse).dt.strftime('%d-%B-%Y')
print (df)
          date   date_new  date_new_en
0  13-mai-2019 2019-05-13  13-May-2019
1  13-mai-2019 2019-05-13  13-May-2019
```

Comment: Please I am new to pandas, can you explain the code above.. I dont quite understand how to incorporate in my piece of code

Comment: @user221459 - Can you edit your question with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Note if you don't have the `dateparser` library.

Install it with even if you use Jupiter notebook.

```
pip3 install dateparser
```

[image]

Or

```
!pip3 install dateparser
```

This library understands over 200 language locales plus numerous formats in a language agnostic fashion.

Parsing generic terms also works:

```
import dateparser
print (dateparser.parse('yesterday')) #2019-05-19 08:08:14.934992
```

And also supports non-Gregorian calendar systems.

Comment: I am using jupyter notebook

Comment: Just open Anaconda command prompt and type `pip3 install dateparser`. @user221459